# Select inside Case When logic

Tags: sql, select, db2, case, create-table

We have the following logic to create a test table flag column.

```
create table "EDI"."TEST" (
    "SHIP_ID" VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    "SHIP_EVNT_CD" VARCHAR(2),
    "AF_FLG" VARCHAR(1) generated always as 
        (case ship_id WHEN (SELECT ship_id FROM EDI.TEST WHERE ship_evnt_cd = 'AF') 
        then 1 else 0 end));
```

The goal is to set the flag for every record matching the ship_id that has that ship_evnt_cd.

We get a constrait error

> A check constraint or generated column that is defined with "SELECT" is invalid.. SQLCODE=-548, SQLSTATE=42621

We've looked it up online but says to redefine the statement and try again. Seems the SELECT does not work, however we managed to create it earlier but had to delete table and then we lost the logic.

We tried also changing the case but without success.

```
(case WHEN ship_id = (SELECT ship_id FROM EDI.TEST WHERE ship_evnt_cd = 'AF') 
then 1 else 0 end));

(case WHEN ship_id IN (SELECT ship_id FROM EDI.TEST WHERE ship_evnt_cd = 'AF') 
then 1 else 0 end));
```

We think something is missing, perhapsany clause, but are stuck here.

Comment: I don't think a generated column can use a subquery.

Comment: oh, do you see a way it could be achieved?

Comment: What does "set the flag for every record matching the ship_id that has that ship_evnt_cd" mean? Please clarify, especially the "that has that ship_evnt_cd" bit

Comment: Just use a view.

Comment: For each ship_id record there are multiple values in ship_evnt_cd, When a ship_id has a particular value, in this case AF, flag should be 1, any other case 0. Despite what is the event for that row, if it has AF on any other of the following lines matching the same ship_id, it should get the flag 1.

Comment: Is your "following lines" comment important? If so what defines a "following line" vs a "preceding line"?  A Relation is a set and has no inherent ordering of it's tuples....

Comment: You would need some "insert_timestamp" column or some such if you need to distinguish "following" from "preceding".  Add a filter on such a column in the  view below if that is what you need  (use a co-related join)

Comment: In fact, the order by ship id could help, but still the select can't be applied. Nevertheless, the Select would bring up everything matching the ship id.

Comment: @JuanIgnacioDurante - Personally, I recommend to never rely on autogenerated ids for anything other than joins (or disambiguations in ordering/partitioning).  Don't rely on them to tell you about the apparent "insert order" - I'm not completely sure that there aren't situations where the inserted id would conflict with something like an `inserted_at` timestamp column.

Comment: Besides views there's also MQTs - Materialized Query Tables, which are essentially persisted (And refreshed) views.

Comment: @JuanIgnacioDurante . . . A computed column can use a user-defined function, so that would be a viable alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what we thought of and could test successfully, although would have prefered not to use...

```
create table EDI.TEST (
    "SHIP_ID" VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    "SHIP_EVNT_CD" VARCHAR(2),
    "AF_FLG" VARCHAR(1) DEFAULT 0
);
```

And then the trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER Flags
after INSERT ON EDI.TEST
referencing new as n
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (n.ship_id in (select ship_id from EDI.TEST where ship_evnt_cd = 'AF'))
UPDATE EDI.TEST SET af_flg = 1
```

Now I need to do this for other 3 columns, so I wonder if I can use the same trigger for multiple column updates wtih different WHEN statement (like a huge CASE WHEN) but well, offtopic...

Comment: Yes, you can use the same trigger, and possibly even the same statement, depending on what exactly the column needs, probably by doing a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger instead.  Note that your current `UPDATE` statement is going to modify the entire table, which is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: Is is also good practice to add a `PRIMARY KEY` on every table, and make columns `NOT NULL` (unless you really *need* to store NULL values for some good reason in a column)

Answer (score 1):

Use a view.

```
CREATE TABLE EDI.TEST_TAB (
    SHIP_ID VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
,   SHIP_EVNT_CD        CHAR(2) NOT NULL
,   PRIMARY KEY(SHIP_ID, SHIP_EVNT_CD)
)
;
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW EDI.TEST AS 
SELECT T.*
,   CASE WHEN SHIP_ID IN (SELECT SHIP_ID FROM EDI.TEST_TAB WHERE SHIP_EVNT_CD = 'AF') 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  AS AF_FLG
FROM
    EDI.TEST_TAB T
;
```

A generated column can't use a subquery
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000927.html

> **AS (generation-expression)**
>       Specifies that the definition of the column is based on an expression. [snip] The
>   generation-expression **cannot contain any of the following** (SQLSTATE
>   42621):
>
> ```
>     Subqueries
>     XMLQUERY or XMLEXISTS expressions
>     Column functions
>     Dereference operations or DEREF functions
>     User-defined or built-in functions that are non-deterministic
>     User-defined functions that use the EXTERNAL ACTION option
>     User-defined functions that are not defined with NO SQL
>     Host variables or parameter markers
>     Special registers and built-in functions that depend on the value of a special register
>     Global variables
>     References to columns defined later in the column list
>     References to other generated columns
>     References to columns of type XML
> ```

Comment: BTW if it's an identifier, then maybe an INTEGER would be better for SHIP_ID. If it is a alphanumeric number, then if fixed width, go for a CHAR()

Comment: The solution is fine, but it is not the approach we want to follow. We think we could set default value and then change it using a trigger AFTER insert, with the same logic. BTW, Ship_id can be alphanumeric and does not have fixed width :P Thanks!

Comment: OK. Yes a trigger would be another way if you insist on having a physical column

Comment: You could add a column that was `GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS (CASE WHEN SHIP_EVNT_CD = 'AF' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` and then get a trigger to overwrite it if it is 0 but other rows for the same ship id have a 'AF' row..

Comment: yes, I think using a trigger on either way is the only option here.

Comment: BTW I was wrong on the `GENERATED BY DEFAULT` option.. that is only for `INDENTITY` or "as-row-change-timestamp-clause" clauses.

Comment: out of interest though, what's wrong with the view approach?  It will be a performance hit, but might be more flexible if you want to change the design...

Comment: We get this data from a remote connection and the idea is to have this base table with all the calculated fields. We are migrating an old solution which as you mention created many views from views  but seems not to like.

Comment: You still might find views are simpler than complex trigger logic... but up to you